# Why is it common to put an underscore before a method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, programming-practices

For example, I noticed that in the jQuery UI widget factory, methods like `_init`, `_start`, `_on`, ect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484424/underscore-prefix-for-property-and-method-names-in-javascript

Comment: Often, an underscore prefix means this method is not meant for public consumption.  I don't know about jQuery UI specifically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been asked and answered at Stack Overflow: [Underscore prefix for property and method names in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4484424/439793)

Comment: @Snowman - While "asked and answered" is a good reason to close, I disagree with what you actually chose; coding convention questions are definitely on-topic here.

Comment: I disagree that "asked and answered _on a different site_" is a good reason to close. However, we can only speculate why the developers of a specific library chose to name their variables as they did, and that's rarely helpful. I won't be re-opening the question only to close it for a different reason, especially since I don't think it's likely to get a better answer than the one it currently has.

Answer (score 8):

The most common use for a leading underscore in my experience is to identify an object member (field/function) that is not supposed to be used by regular users. This means the member is regarded as "private". Because JavaScript doesn't enforce visibility modifiers (everything's considered "public"), it's common to use coding conventions like this to indicate visibility. As a commenter stated, members with a leading underscore are considered more specifically to have "internal" scope. They can be freely accessed within the library, or by those writing extensions to it, but should not be accessed by users of the library.

Comment: It isn't supposed to be called by the library user, but it *is* supposed to be public otherwise not even jQuery could call it.  There are ways of hiding functions/members in javascript so that only the one defining it can use them.